# Why does recording an animation not record the initial position of an object?

Tags: animation, timeline

I am doing a simple animation. I click the record button in the bottom timeline and then move objects in the viewport. But somehow the yellow diamond mark ( recorder ) does not appear on 0/1. ie, the Record action won't recognize the initial position. I tried manually " add keyframes " at that point without success.

It would nice if anyone call tell me how to include the initial point of timeline also as a part of the animation.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to accomplish. By "record button" are you referring to the Auto Keying feature? If you want to include frame 0 in your animation, set the Start Frame to 0 in the top right of the Timeline editor. If you're unable to add keyframes, you may need to set a Keying Set in the Keying dropdown of the Timeline.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is 1 or 0. I just want the animation to go back to 1/0 when the cycle is over and start from there during the first cycle as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is 'keyframe'. First select the object you want to animate, press <kbd>I</kbd> on your keyboard while your cursor is somewhere in blender viewport and a menu will pop up, select 'LocRotScale' since you are a beginner, ignore the rest.

A yellow diamond symbol will be added on your timeline. (Note it will be hidden if you deselect the object, but not deleted. Select the object again to see it.)

This is called keyframing.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just set the first frame to 0 (it is 1 by default).

See the following image: [image]

Comment: I am trying to add the " yellow diamond mark " to 1. I said zero due to lack of experience. Even 1 is fine as long as the animation starts from it. As for the record button I mentioned, it is the round white button which is just above the timeline block among play and next buttons Thanks.

Comment: okay, see my second answer instead, and accept if it is what you are looking for.